# How can I detect if two elements are touching

Tags: javascript, dom, element

So I was wondering if you could test for two elements touching each other running a if statement. I know that I am new to javascript and I do not know as much as others, but I couldn't find out how to test for two elements touching.

For example I would want it to be something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("element1");
var el2 = document.getElementById("element2");

if (el1 touching el2) {
//code
//code
}
```

Yes I know this is not how you do it but I would like to know if there was a certain way you could tell if two elements are touching...

Comment: Yes, this is rather complicated to do, but it is possible. Now all that is left is to do it :D Good luck.

Comment: Define "touch" term first.

Comment: yeah I am wondering how I should do this?

Comment: Start with [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) probably.  And consider if you want to take z-index into account.  Since they are both boxes, you could probably use [AABB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512319/what-is-aabb-collision-detection) collision detection to see if they are intersecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get their boxes.  Then use a collision test, such as [AABB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22512393/691711), to see if they are intersecting.

Note that I don't think this will work if you apply any crazy rotation transforms to either element.