# Three.JS lookat

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection

I have a object that looks to another object. But when I do my collision detection. He doesn't sees the rotation wish I do with the `LookAt`. But he uses his default rotation. Why doesn't he uses the rotation wish I do with the `LookAt`?

This is the problem:

[image]

The blue one is the default. The green one shows the blue one with the `LookAt`.

Why does LookAt does not effect the collision detection?

My collision detection: (I make a RTS game that is why I only use X and Z)

```
function collisionXZ(o1, o2) {
    if (Math.abs(o1.position.x - o2.position.x) > (o1.geometry.parameters.width + o2.geometry.parameters.width) / 2)
        return false;
    if (Math.abs(o1.position.z - o2.position.z) > (o1.geometry.parameters.depth + o2.geometry.parameters.depth) / 2)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `LookAt`? You're rotating the object with the `THREE.Object3D.lookAt()` method, that's it? What do you mean by _collision detection_? Do your collision detection algorithm uses the `matrixWorld` for testing the objects?

Comment: @neeh Thanks for your answer. Yes I rotate a 3D object with `LookAt()`. No my collision detection doesn't use matrixWorld. Do I need that? I updated my post with my collision detection. Maybe you have some feedback..? many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`THREE.Object3D.lookAt()` changes the `rotation` of your object, not its `position`.

Thus, if you want to test whether those two rectangles collide, you have to take the `rotation` into account.

Your function looks like an [AABB test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512319/what-is-aabb-collision-detection), which is (in most cases) only used during the *broad phase* of a collision detection system. Basically, the purpose of this test is to detect which object **might** be colliding, to avoid unnecessary greedy collision tests but it's **not a real collision test** in itself.

I think you're better off using a library for collision detection that provides primitive tests (Rectangle over Rectangle, Rectangle over Circle, ...)

Comment: Thanks for you great answer. Do you have any suggestions for a libary to do collision detention with Three JS?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473755/how-to-detect-collision-in-three-js) and maybe [physi.js](https://chandlerprall.github.io/Physijs/)