# Point Cloud Library Rotation of Axis Alligned Bounding Box

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am using the Axis Aligned bounding box in PCL after clustering the clouds. I use it vehicle detection and tracking application. Is there any way to rotate the axis aligned box according to the cloud as i need the yaw information from the box.

Thank you

[using an OOB doesn't generate a box representative of the vehicle click here for ref. image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj5yZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

**Using pcl::MomentOfInertiaEstimation**

Official [PCL tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/moment_of_inertia.php) on: Moment of inertia and eccentricity based descriptors.

If you're interested in yaw, then you need to use the OBB (oriented bounding box), rather than the [AABB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512319/what-is-aabb-collision-detection) (axis aligned bounding box). AABB is, as the name suggests, aligned with the axis, and is basically equivalent to taking the min/max of each coordinate. OBB in PCL is based on the eigen vectors of the [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (directions of maximum variance).

Code (from the tutorial) for the extraction of the OBB:

```
pcl::MomentOfInertiaEstimation <pcl::PointXYZ> feature_extractor;
feature_extractor.setInputCloud (cloud);
feature_extractor.compute ();

pcl::PointXYZ min_point_OBB;
pcl::PointXYZ max_point_OBB;
pcl::PointXYZ position_OBB;
Eigen::Matrix3f rotational_matrix_OBB;
Eigen::Vector3f major_vector, middle_vector, minor_vector;
Eigen::Vector3f mass_center;

feature_extractor.getOBB (min_point_OBB, max_point_OBB, position_OBB, rotational_matrix_OBB);
feature_extractor.getEigenVectors (major_vector, middle_vector, minor_vector);
feature_extractor.getMassCenter (mass_center);
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_moment_of_inertia_estimation.html#details):

> Note that in order to get the OBB, each vertex of the given AABB
>   (specified with min_point and max_point) must be rotated with the
>   given rotational matrix (rotation transform) and then positioned.

So to get the final OBB - 
The coordinates:

```
Eigen::Vector3f p1 (min_point_OBB.x, min_point_OBB.y, min_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p2 (min_point_OBB.x, min_point_OBB.y, max_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p3 (max_point_OBB.x, min_point_OBB.y, max_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p4 (max_point_OBB.x, min_point_OBB.y, min_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p5 (min_point_OBB.x, max_point_OBB.y, min_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p6 (min_point_OBB.x, max_point_OBB.y, max_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p7 (max_point_OBB.x, max_point_OBB.y, max_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p8 (max_point_OBB.x, max_point_OBB.y, min_point_OBB.z);

p1 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p1 + position;
p2 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p2 + position;
p3 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p3 + position;
p4 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p4 + position;
p5 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p5 + position;
p6 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p6 + position;
p7 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p7 + position;
p8 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p8 + position;
```

**Using pcl::pca**

[PCL Documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/classpcl_1_1_p_c_a.html#details)

[Tutorial at codextechnicanum.blogspot.co.il](http://codextechnicanum.blogspot.co.il/2015/04/find-minimum-oriented-bounding-box-of.html)

If you're just interested in the direction vector of the vehicle, then assuming it is along the major eigen vector:

```
pcl::PCA<pcl::PointXYZ> pca(cloud, true);
Eigen::Matrix3f eigen_vector = pca.getEigenVectors(); // returns a matrix where the columns are the axis of your bounding box    
Eigen::Vector3f direction = eigen_vector.col(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I tried using OOB since the points reflected from the vehicle covers only partial surface of the vehicle which depends on the vehicle position w.r.t sensor. So an OOB does't give a box that is representative of a vehicle that is there is no plane of the box parallel to the ground

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this. I used OOBB with restricting the rotation only in z axis, so the other two axis rotation is not considered

Eigen::Vector3f ea = rotational_matrix_OBB.eulerAngles(0, 0, yaw);

Comment: Can you share the solution on how not to include rotation in Z axis?

Comment: @VictorSanchez edited my comment. For OBB you can create a rotation matrix and give that as input when creating a OBB in PCL